# Permutations of $\{1,2,...,n\}$ with $q$-th number $5$ and either $1$ or $2$ earlier

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Given an ordered set $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5,...,n\}$. We now want to calculate the number of permutations for which the following holds:

1.) The number $1$ or the number $2$ occurs among the first $q-1$ numbers.

2.) The $q$-th number is equal to $5$.

I have tried the following:
$$
\left({2 \choose 1}\cdot {n-2-1 \choose q-2}(n-q)!\right)(q-1)! + \left({n-2 \choose q-3}(n-q)!\right)(q-1)! 
$$
The first term should cover the number of permutations where either a 1 or a 2 occurs among the first $q-1$ numbers and the second term should cover the number of permutations where 1 and 2 occur. For $n = 11, q=6$ the result is wrong and I don't see where the error is.

Is there an easier way to calculate this?

Comment: I'm not sure where your various binomial coefficients are coming from, but I don't see how you've accounted for the fact that in your second term, the $1$ and $2$ can occur in either order.  I've suggested a simpler (in my opinion) answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are $(n-1)!$ permutations for which the $q$th entry is $5$ (assuming $n \geq 5$).  Of these, there are $(n-q)((n-q)-1)(n-3)!$ permutations for which both $1$ and $2$ occur after the $q$th entry.  So the number of permutations that satisfy both conditions is:

$$(n-1)!-(n-q)((n-q)-1)(n-3)!=(n-3)![(n-1)(n-2)-(n-q)((n-q)-1)].$$

Thus, for $n=11, q=6$, the answer should be $8!(90-20)=70 \cdot 8!=2,822,400$.